# Where is not "" empty

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to write a statement using CI but I am having an issue writing a `WHERE is not = " "`

Can I have an example I so far have

```
$empty = array('');
$this->db->where_not_in("$this->_table['shop_shipping_rules']}.shop_shipping_rule_name", $empty);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this with simple `where()`

```
$this->db->where("$this->_table['shop_shipping_rules']}.shop_shipping_rule_name !='' OR 
$this->_table['shop_shipping_rules']}.shop_shipping_rule_name IS NOT NULL
");
```

**Edit**

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('mytable');
 $this->db->where("shop_shipping_rule_name IS NOT NULL AND shop_shipping_rule_name !=''")
$query = $this->db->get();
```

OR

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('mytable');
 $this->db->where(" TRIM(shop_shipping_rule_name) IS NOT NULL AND TRIM(shop_shipping_rule_name) !=''")
$query = $this->db->get();
```

[**Active Record Class**](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

[**Mysql TRIM()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim)

Comment: Its still giving me data like ` ["shop_shipping_rule_name"]=> string(0) ""`

Comment: @JessMcKenzie what exactly you need ?

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
$this->db->where('field_name IS NOT NULL');
```

Or this way:

```
$this->db->where('field_name !=' , '');
```

Comment: Its still bring all data through

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `""` with `where`

```
$this->db->where("$this->_table['shop_shipping_rules']}.shop_shipping_rule_name !=", "");
```